# Is there a way to list all the Azure websites I have created, and delete them?

Tags: azure, web, azure-web-app-service

When I create a new project in Visual Studio, and set the project to be hosted on Azure, I get the dialog to name the website URL.  I have gone through a number of tutorials, etc., and each time I created a new website on Azure.  I would like to get a list of all of the websites I created on Azure, and I would like to delete some of them.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Can't you just login into Azure Portal and see the list of websites there? There you can delete them as well. Or are your looking for some other way to manage the websites.

Comment: You could also do it from Visual Studio by connecting to Azure in the Server Explorer window.

Comment: I may be obtuse, but I don't see a "Websites" tab in the Azure Portal, all I see is "Web Apps".  Are these equivalent?  What I am talking about when I say "Website" is the URL "<mywebsite>.azurewebsites.net".  I want a list of all of these URL's I created.

Comment: Yes, Web Apps and Web Sites are the same. the .azurewebsites.net sites you made are under Web Apps in the portal.

Comment: @Stephenosella, FYI, Web Sites was renamed to Web Apps back in the Spring. Hence the two different names you see

Answer (score 1):

Both comments above are valid: The [New Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), the [Old Azure Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), Visual Studio (Server Explorer in VS2013 and Cloud Explorer in VS2015) are good resources to do what you want. A third resource is using the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) and finally - using [Azure Power Shell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/).